# SQL Server Incorrect syntax near '11'

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I get the error `Incorrect syntax near '11'.` in SQL Server.

There is a stored procedure `SP_TEST`:

```
...
@ALISTARIHI datetime
...
AS
BEGIN
...
exec('CONVERT(DATETIME,'+@ALISTARIHI+')')
```

Calling SP_TEST:

```
exec SP_TEST '08.11.2013'
```

As I mentioned above, I get error

> Incorrect syntax near '11'

when I call. How can I fix it?

NOTE: Some of the above code looks

Comment: Why would you want to convert a datetime to a datetime, if that is already its type?

Comment: try `exec SP_TEST '08/11/2013'`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I used a structure that is required by code, but the "Convert" continues even after you remove the same problem again.

Comment: Thank you Marc, take care of it! But the problem is still going on

Comment: @MehmetInce, I've tried it, but the problem is not solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So many things wrong.

1. The comment about converting a datetime to a datetime is spot on. Why are you doing this? And why is your datetime in an ambiguous format? I have absolutely no idea if that is supposed to be August 11th or November 8th. Try using `yyyymmdd`.
2. Assuming you do need to do this, why are you doing it in dynamic SQL?
3. Assuming you do need dynamic SQL, why is your statement incomplete? What does this do, even if you put string delimiters around the value?

   ```
   CONVERT(DATETIME, '20131108');
   ```

   Oh, that's right:

   > Msg 156, Level 15, State 1
   >
   > Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

   The statement isn't even complete. So maybe you meant:

   ```
   EXEC('SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'''+@ALISTARIHI+''')')
   ```

But in reality, [you probably want something like this instead](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @d);';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@d DATETIME', @ALISTARIHI;
```

But I still don't understand why you're converting a datetime to a datetime.

P.S. Why would you name your variable something so long and difficult to type?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass `08.11.2013` as parameter and after concatenating in EXEC you will receive `CONVERT(DATETIME,08.11.2013)` , i.e. you will not have string - this is the cause for ERROR. It must be `CONVERT(DATETIME,'08.11.2013')`

The command `exec('CONVERT(DATETIME,'+@ALISTARIHI+')')` also does not make any sense to me. 
It is wrong. Must be `exec('SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'''+@ALISTARIHI+''')')`.
And the result will be outside of the scope of the current code (because of the EXEC).